# sys.argv to python readable string

Tags: python, node.js, utf-8, spawn, sys

I have a node app that calls a spawn python process like so:

```
const python = spawn('python3', ['python/rimas_definitivas.py', input]);
```

the input variable comes from a form in the browser, and it usually has special caracters, like "á", "õ", ...
in the python script the variable is read like this:

```
variable= sys.argv[1]
```

when the input doesn't have any special caracters the program runs fine, but when it does it doesnt work.
also, i find these prints very strange, and they could be related to the problem:

for the input world "língua":

```
>>>variable= sys.argv[1]
>>>print(variable)
língua
>>>print([variable, ])
['l\udcc3\udcadngua']
```

the second input shouldn't be ['língua']?

It maybe has to do with utf-8/unicode, but i'm a begginer and I really don't know what to do...

Comment: `['l\udcc3\udcadngua']` has no sense as both `\udcc3` and `\udcad` are low surrogates…